# Retrieve Skype recent chats

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pull-out the content of the recent Skype messages window, which is contained under the TChatContentControl window class (a child of TConversationForm, which at its turn is a child of tSkMainForm). I use C++.

I was trying to use the WM_GETTEXT SendMessage method without success.
I was further trying to use the AccessibleObjectFromEvent method, retrieving the value/name of the IAccessible interface without success.

I was further expecting that Skype would store this data as html and used WM_HTML_GETOBJECT messages to interpret IHTMLElement structures (works perfectly with Yahoo Messenger), but still without success.

Anybody more experienced did it before and knows how is Skype storing this data and what is the way out of it?

Many thanks for your kind support.

In an attempt to revitalize a bit this thread, let me share with you a piece of simplified code that
will do with Yahoo Messenger what I'm trying to achieve with Skype:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Oleacc.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <mshtml.h>    

#pragma comment (lib, "Oleacc.lib")

void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime) 
{
    char className[50];
    GetClassName(hwnd, className, 50);

    if (strcmp(className, "CTabbedIMHost") == 0)
    {
        HWND wndbase = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "CConvWndBase", NULL);
        HWND container = FindWindowEx(wndbase, 0, "YHTMLContainer", NULL);
        HWND exp = FindWindowEx(container, 0, "Internet Explorer_Server", NULL);

        if (NULL != exp)
        {
            CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> ieDoc;
            LRESULT lRes;

            UINT uMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(_T("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT"));
            SendMessageTimeout(exp, uMsg, 0L, 0L, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, (DWORD*)&lRes);

            HRESULT hRes = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument2, 0, (void**)&ieDoc);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
            {
                CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pHTMLElement;
                hRes = ieDoc->get_body(&pHTMLElement);
                BSTR bstrBodyText;
                pHTMLElement->get_innerText(&bstrBodyText);

                // MessageBoxW(NULL, bstrBodyText, L"Yahoo Messenger", MB_OK | MB_ICONASTERISK);
            }
        }
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdParam, int iCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    HWINEVENTHOOK LHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE, 0, WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWinEvent(LHook);
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```